# Scala version upgrade from 2.12 to 2.13 ( Incompatible spark-dynamoDB library )

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to upgrade scala version from 2.12 to 2.13

we use this libraryDependency to write to Dynamodb

https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb

`"com.audienceproject" %% "spark-dynamodb" % "latest"`

but in their docs they mentioned this is not compatible with scala 2.13

i tried looking for different spark-dynamodb libraries but couldn’t find ..

then worked to make this  specific microservice remain on 2.12 and rest migrated to 2.13 that too is giving a lot of errors ( which i think is not a good soln' not sure)

please suggest what thing i should try more?

the write function is like..

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(path)
.select(col("\*"), col("date_et").as("partition_date"))

// Write to DynamoDB

df
.repartition(1000)
.write
.options(dynamoOptions)
.option("inferSchema", "false")
.option("throughput", "10000")
.option("targetCapacity", "10000")
.option("region", conf.tableRegion())
.option("writeBatchSize", conf.writeBatchSize())
.dynamodb(conf.table())
```

Comment: Find another connector for DynamoDB to Spark that is updated or write your own.